# Edit description in Ms teams composeExtensions.commands

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#composeextensionscommands, there is a limit on the size of description in composeExtensions.commands. Is there a workaround for that?

Also, on adding multiple commands, the popup shows a "2 more" option,
is there any way to customize this, i want to show just 2 main commands in popup and other commands
to open when user clicks "More Filters".

[image]

I want something like ...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is a limit on the size of description in
> composeExtensions.commands. Is there a workaround for that?

> Is there any way to customize this, i want to show just 2 main
> commands in popup

These are not customizable fields. This is by design.
Please feel free to post feature suggestions on [Microsoft Teams feedback portal on UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform).